# how to view different detailView of selected row on iOS Master Detail

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.5, master-detail, ios5

I'm working on master detail app and i would like to view different detailView of selected row. and to be my question clear i give you example here:

Master Detail

---

detail 1         >

---

detail 2         >

---

the target is when i press [detail 1 >] give me self detailview of detail 1 row. and press [detail 2] give self detailview of detail 2 row. i think it's clear. also add customize buttons, images inside every detail view if possible!!

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I've tried switch method detail 1 case 0 and detail 2 case 1 but doesn't change anything still i get detail 2 same in detail 1?

Comment: Don't you think `switch` argument is incorrect then ?

Comment: I think getting some code up would be useful. Can you show what you've got so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
DetailViewController *detailView = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
detailView.tagValue = 1;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
```

You can send a tag value to `detailView` and based on this value you can show different views.
Like make a property like `@property(nonatomic)NSInteger tagValue;` in .h class of detailView and synthesize it in .m class. Now you can send the `tagValue` from master Class like this

Now you can check value of `tagValue` in `DetailViewController` and based on this you can create your View.
I think it is clear now. But if you still have any issue, you can write your code.

Comment: still same problem. but using your code let me back 2 time and give me an error pushing to detailView:
012-10-25 00:38:36.344 MasterDetail[9607:11303] nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
2012-10-25 00:38:36.710 MasterDetail[9607:11303] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
2012-10-25 00:38:36.716 MasterDetail[9607:11303] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <DetailViewController: 0x7178790>.

Comment: DetailViewController *detailView = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
detailView.tagValue = 1;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 
{
    DetailViewController *detailView = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
     
    detailView.tagValue = indexPath.row;
     
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
}
```

we need to give detailView.tagValue = indexPath.row;